# How to customize multiple checkbox in CakePHP 4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am adding multiple checkbox but facing issue to adding classes to parent div.

HTML output should be like this

```
<div class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-checkbox"> 
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="colorCheck1" checked=""> 
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="colorCheck1">Primary</label> 
</div>
```

I am trying to use this code

```
<?php 
$list = ['1'=>'Select 1','2'=>'Select 2']; /*Array of list */

echo $this->Form->select('profile_ids', $list, [ 
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'class'=>'custom-control-input', 
    'label' => [
        'class' => 'custom-control-label'
    ], 
    'templates' => [
        'inputContainer' => '<div class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-checkbox">{{content}}</div>'
    ] 
]);
```

and i am getting this code in html that is not what i want

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="profile-ids-13">
        <input type="checkbox" name="profile_ids[]" value="13" id="profile-ids-13" class="custom-control-input" templates="<div class=&quot;custom-control custom-control-primary custom-checkbox&quot;>{{content}}</div>">default
    </label>
</div>
```

Please help how to get desired checkbox.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `templates` option can only be used with the `FormHelper::control()` method, element specific methods will not recognize it, and only use what has been configured for the form helper in general, and only what's required to build the specific control.

Furthermore, multi-checkbox controls use different templates than single checkboxes. For a multi-checkbox, `inputContainer` will be the wrapper around the whole set of checkboxes, not the one around the individual checkboxes themselves, for that you'd have to customize `checkboxWrapper` instead. On top of that a change to the `nestingLabel` template is required in for inputs to be placed outside of the labels.

### Creating specific elements directly

So, if you wanted to use `select()` directly, then you'd have to configure the global templates of the form helper:

```php
$this->Form->setTemplates([
    'checkboxWrapper' => '<div class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-checkbox">{{label}}</div>',
    'nestingLabel' => '{{hidden}}{{input}}<label{{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>',
]);

$list = [
    1 => 'Select 1',
    2 => 'Select 2',
];

echo $this->Form->select('profile_ids', $list, [
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'class'=>'custom-control-input',
    'label' => [
        'class' => 'custom-control-label'
    ],
]);
```

This would create the following HTML:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="profile_ids" id="profile-ids" value=""/>
<div class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="profile_ids[]" value="1" id="profile-ids-1" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="profile-ids-1">Select 1</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="profile_ids[]" value="2" id="profile-ids-2" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="profile-ids-2">Select 2</label>
</div>
```

If you want the templates to only apply to this `select()` call, then you could call `$this->Form->templater()->push();` before setting the templates, and `$this->Form->templater()->pop();` after calling `$this->Form->select(...)`, that way the current templater state will be buffered in beforehand, and restored after you generated the element.

### Creating elements using `control()`

And if you wanted to use `control()` instead, then you'd need to be aware that the `label` option will not affect the labels of the invidual checkboxes then, but the one of the wrapper. In order to configure the nested labels, you'd have to either pass the label options in the select options, or hardcode the attributes in the `nestingLabel` template, which you have to modify anyways:

```php
$list = [
    [
        'label' => [
            'class' => 'custom-control-label'
        ],
        'value' => 1,
        'text' => 'Select 1',
    ],
    [
        'label' => [
            'class' => 'custom-control-label'
        ],
        'value' => 2,
        'text' => 'Select 2',
    ],
];

echo $this->Form->control('profile_ids', [
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $list,
    'class' => 'custom-control-input',
    'templates' => [
        'checkboxWrapper' => '<div class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-checkbox">{{label}}</div>',
        'nestingLabel' => '{{hidden}}{{input}}<label{{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>',
    ]
]);
```

or with hardcoded label attributes in the template:

```php
$list = [
    1 => 'Select 1',
    2 => 'Select 2',
];

echo $this->Form->control('profile_ids', [
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $list,
    'class' => 'custom-control-input',
    'templates' => [
        'checkboxWrapper' => '<div class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-checkbox">{{label}}</div>',
        'nestingLabel' => '{{hidden}}{{input}}<label class="custom-control-label"{{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>',
    ]
]);
```

Both would produce the following HTML:

```html
<div class="input select">
    <label for="profile-ids">Profile Ids</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="profile_ids" id="profile-ids" value=""/>
    <div class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="profile_ids[]" value="1" id="profile-ids-1" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="profile-ids-1">Select 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-control-primary custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="profile_ids[]" value="2" id="profile-ids-2" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="profile-ids-2">Select 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

ps. you might want to check out plugins like [**`friendsofcake/bootstrap-ui`**](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui) which can do all that for you transparently.

### See also

- **[Cookbook > View > Helpers > Form > Customizing the Templates FormHelper Uses](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses)**
- **[Cookbook > View > Helpers > Form > Options for Control](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-control)**